# How do I change the colors of each TabBar navigation bar title individually?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a TabBar with 5 tabs. For each tab, I want them to have a different navigation bar color. How can I have a different color for each item?

For all other navigation bar titles, I'd like them to have black color.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set at each view controller the bar color with this code:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor .redColor
```

While this is to set your bar titles to black:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.blackColor()]
```

Answer (score 0):

In the storyboard you'll probably see a navigation controller for each tab:

[image]

Select one of these controllers and then in the document outline select the navigation bar:

[image]

Next, in the Attributes Inspector, modify the background color:

[image]

You don't need to do anything to get black navigation bar title text. That's the default.

Voilà!!

[image]